# How to get ScrollView for Two UICollectionView in swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, scrollview, uipagecontrol

**As i have used this code to get current page index in pageControl. But this function can't distinguish if scrollView is for Which collectionView.**

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if collectionView == self.brandCollectionView {
            brandPageControl.currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x) / Int(scrollView.frame.width)
        } else {
            brandPageControl.currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x) / Int(scrollView.frame.width)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is working :

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       if scrollView == self.collectionView {
           //code for this scrollView1
        } else {
             //code for this scrollView2
        }
    }
```